# What is a good tag synonym for perseverance of the saints?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried adding the tag perseverance-of-the-saints to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4461/why-does-calvanism-need-the-doctrine-of-perseverance-of-the-saints-if-it-believe) but I got an error telling me it exceeded the max tag length of 25 characters. What is a good synonym for it?

Answer (score 2):

The tag is now [perseverance-of-saints](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perseverance-of-saints).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this doesn't open a can of worms, since I know the various terms are often used by different groups with different theology in these areas... but what about [eternal-security](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eternal-security)?  Even if it's not considered a precise equal to the doctrine of perseverance of the saints, it's pretty close, and for the purpose of tags, they're probably equal, no?  In other words a question asking about one could just as well be asking about the other, for the purpose of categorization and searching.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [perserverance-of-the-sain](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perserverance-of-the-sain) ? :}

Not very helpful, I know.  Maybe [perserverance-of-the-snts](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perserverance-of-the-snts)?

OK, these are bad ideas.  But it's all I got.

Answer (score -3):

What about mapping this tag and

- [total-depravity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-depravity)
- [unconditional-election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unconditional-election)
- [limited-atonement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-atonement)
- [irresistible-grace](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irresistible-grace)

All to either the [calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calvinism) or a new tag [tulip](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tulip)

This would clean up 5 tags at once and solve a character limit problem...

Comment: I would prefer tulip because its less of an abstraction than Calvinism, but it might confuse people not familiar with Calvinism.